# while loop to check for user input not in for loop

Tags: shell-script, for

I am listing files from a folder and taking an input from the user to select one of the files.

```
files=$(ls ~/VideoExtract/*.avi)
i=1
for j in $files
do
echo "$i.$j"
file[i]=$j
i=$(( i + 1 ))
done
echo ""
echo ""
read -p "Enter the serial number from the above list : " input
clear
```

Suppose if I have 3 files, the above code lists all three files listed with serial numbers 1,2,3.  I want to validate if the user provides the correct input and not break the code till receiving a correct input.  To do this, I have used a while loop after the above code

```
while [[ "$input" =~ ["$i"] ]]
do
echo "Please provide a serial number from the list given below."
files=$(ls ~/VideoExtract/*.avi)
i=1
for j in $files
do
echo "$i.$j"
file[i]=$j
i=$(( i + 1 ))
done
read -p "Enter the serial number from the above list : " input
done
```

This does returns the list of files again.  The problem is, if I have 3 files, and if I type 4, the loop continues to work, but if I provide 5 instead, the loop breaks and moves on to the next line of the code.  I am not sure if the problem is in line

```
while [[ "$input" =~ ["$i"] ]]
```

or

```
i=$(( i + 1 ))
```

Instead of `=~` I have tried with `!=` and `! $input == $i` and similar other combinations, such as with and without [] for $i.  Nothing seem to work.

How do I run the while loop till the time the user provides a valid input that is within the range of $i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(On a mobile so a somewhat shorter than I'd prefer)

`=~` is a Regular Expression match. You don't want this here. Use `-lt` (less than) or `-le` (less than or equal) instead.

There are also a number of other problems with your code

- don't use `ls` to list a set of files, just use the set of files directly `files=(~/VideoExtract/*.avi)`
- quote your variables when you use them `file["$i"]="$j"`
- let the shell control the expansion of `$files` when you iterate over it `for j in "${files[@]}"`
- not strictly necessary, but indenting your code blocks will make the code far far easier to read

Comment: thank you....and I will include your other suggestions as well.